# Unable to call function on querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have a responsive navigation bar. On mobile view, when I click the hamburger the navbar-active class moves the navbar from

`transform: translateX(-100%);` to `transform: translateX(0);`

Now when I click on any anchor link, I want the navigation bar to go to back to `transform: translateX(-100%);`

So I made a function for it:

```
navLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.remove('navbar-active');
});
```

But the console is showing:

> navLink.addEventListener is not a function

Here is the HTML

```
<ul class = 'navbar'>
    <li class = 'nav-link'><a href = '#about' tabindex = '-1'>link-1</a></li>
    <li class = 'nav-link'><a href = '#ebooks' tabindex = '-1'>link-2</a></li>
    <li class = 'nav-link'><a href = '#blog' tabindex = '-1'>link-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.navbar');
    const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('navbar-active');
    });

    navLink.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.remove('navbar-active');
    });
}

navSlide();
```

Things I tried to solve it:

1. It works when I use `const navLink = document.querySelector('.nav-link');` instead of `const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');` but it works only on first element.
2. I tried to add `const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link a');` but no luck again.

I'm a beginner in JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list... you should loop through that list and access every single item returned from the selector.

Comment: I tried this
`navLink.addEventListener('click', () => {        
        navLink.forEach((link) => {
            nav.classList.remove('navbar-active');
        });
    });`

But, it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your `forEach` is iterating storing the i-th element on `link` variable but you are not using it and you indulge on using `nav` instead

Comment: I didn't get you. I use `nav` there because I want to remove the `navbar-active` from `nav` when I click on the `navLink`

Comment: yes that part is actually correct indeed... the problem was keeping on using navLink like it was an element instead of a list as I suggested before. Its value is returned by querySelectorAll. If you followed the link I posted, you found exactly how to deal with the list it returns. Instead of calling addEventListener on the list you should call it on its items

Comment: Hey, thank you. I solved it by:
for(var i = 0; i < navLink.length; i++) {
        navLink[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            nav.classList.remove('navbar-active');
            burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
        })
    }

I know it is hard to deal with newbies like me. Thank you for your help. You are a life savior.